# Biblatex: Date-Fields B.C.

Tags: biblatex, datetime

If I wanted to quote a book written 45 B.C. - how would I have to enter the year in fields like `origyear` or `year` to cite (and list it in the bibliography) accordingly? Using the `authoryear`-style …

Comment: Are you citing precisely the edition of 45 BC? I don't think so. You're probably citing some later edition, which wasn't published BC, I guess.

Comment: The point of the date in author-date styles is to allow other people to find the precise edition you used (in case they want to check up on you, say), not the supposed date of 'publication' of (say) a work of Cicero's.  I recommend following using real publication data and mention the date 45 BC in the accompanying prose of the text; e.g.: 'In 45 BC So-and-so wrote *De aliquo ad aliquem*...'.

Comment: FYI: I am formatting my citations in some special cases like this: `(authorname origyear/year page)`, and sort them in the bibliography with `sortyear` … In the end I tried to put a minus in front of the 45 (`origyear = {-45}, sortyear = {-45}`) - seems to work fine. :)

Comment: Would you consider the comment above to be an answer to my question?

Comment: It's your question, so you know what best constitutes the 'correct' answer to it.  And you are certainly allowed to post an answer to one of your own questions if you wish.  From a bibliographical perspective, I think you are missing the point, but I have no special authority in this regard.  And it is entirely possible that the bibliography is being used in a special way where a date of '45 BCE' makes sense....

Comment: @moewe -- Sure, though it is kind of a non-answer...

Comment: @jon There are some style manuals which require using e.g. 'origyear/year' or whatever. Moreover, there is something odd about 'As Cicero noted, this is a great idea (1999, 54-65)' if you use author/year citations in the text. Though I know some journals will insist on daft things like 'As Kant pointed out... (2004a)', not seeming to understand how weird this looks.

Comment: @cfr -- Indeed.  I am well aware of this fact.  My own view is that such texts, which are the work of modern editors should be listed under their names, not Cicero's.  Something like: L. D. Reynolds, ed. (1998). *M. Tulli Ciceronis de finibus bonorum et malorum libri quinque*. Oxford: Clarendon Press.  But I know not many people agree with me.  Anyway, for classical and medieval studies, it does not make sense to use 'origdate' field for the supposed date of 'publication', which is often uncertain anyway, but to stress the original modern publication date + reprint date or what have you....

Comment: @jon It might be a non answer, but - in may opinion - the best we can do.

Answer (score 3):

Outside of special circumstances, the normal goal of a bibliographical reference is to provide the information one requires to track down the citation.  What this means is that if you used a specific edition of, say, Cicero's *De natura deorum*, the reference needs to include not the date of when Cicero is thought to have written it (45 BCE), but the date your edition was printed.

Moreover, since *all* extant manuscripts of Cicero's work were copied in the middle ages, there is no edition from 45 BCE, and so it is kind of disingenuous to write 45 BCE insofar as it implicitly suggests we use a text as Cicero wrote it.  (The point of a critical edition is of course to reconstruct the text to be as close to what Cicero wrote as we can, but I believe it is important for us to remember that we *do not* have in our possession a text written in 45 BCE.)  And of course a translation is even less the text Cicero wrote and certainly does not deserve to be thought of as written in 45 BCE...  My preference would be to include in my essay/book itself the point that Cicero is thought to have written the work in 45 BCE, and to let the date of the modern edition serve in the citations and bibliography as a subtle reminder that we rely on the work of the editor(s) when we talk about what Cicero wrote.

That said, it may well be possible to trick `biblatex` into doing things sorting things you need by using the `sortyear` field.  The OP writes `sortyear = {-45}`, but I would suggest using a four digit date such as

```
@Book{...
  sortdate = {-0045},
  ...
}
```